# Can't use awk in terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk

I want to use awk command to do something,
I input `awk` in terminal,
but the terminal show me that

> awk: cannot open /home/user/myexe/external_symbols.awk (No such file
>   or directory)

Someone tell to make an alias in your shell,but I  would not ..,can someone help me..

Then I try to input :`which -a awk`

terminal show `:/usr/bin/awk`

input: `type awk`

terminal show: `awk is aliased to 'awk -f /home/user/myexe/external_symbols.awk'`
How can i change the aliase which path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `unalias awk` at the command line to remove the alias.

Comment: As said, `unalias awk` will work in the current terminal. Also check your ~/.bashrc file. Look for a line that sets the awk alias. You can remove that line.

Comment: @Jake223 I remove the alias,then do I need to set something or without ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you're asking about what Matt said, bring up a file called `/home/yourusername/.bashrc` in your favorite text editor and look for a line that stars with `alias awk=...`. delete that line.

Comment: @Jake223 It work,but I don't understand why have to delete the alias of awk?Is it awk can't use alias?

Comment: `awk` is a program you want to run, but when you type `awk` at the prompt, it looks first for aliases and *then* at programs that could be executed. So if there is an alias in place, it will prevent you from running the program.

Comment: @Jake223 I changed the path of awk that alias,like awk='awk -f /usr/bin/awk',but I input the same command ,it doesn't work.. It shows me that "awk: 1:unexpected character 0x7f   , awk /usr/bin/awk: line 1: runway regular expression /xx"  Why input same command your method can make it work,but my method that doesn't work ?

Comment: you want `awk` to be `awk` or `/usr/bun/awk`, not `awk -f something else`.